# Firebase 3: create user from backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase upgrade from 2 to 3 add a separation from "clients" (web, ios, android) and server (java & node.js), with the introduction of service account.

To implement a passwordless system (with Java), I used to create users from the backend (using the firebase-client-jvm lib), but with the new version, it seems to not be possible in a proper way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is currently no way to create users from the server SDK. We're working on a solution, but have no timeline yet. This has been asked/answered before, so I'll mark as a duplicate.